# Can't install bootstrap using npm

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4

I can't install bootstrap using node package manager console.
There are some errors showing in the console.
Can I use only a `CDN` to my website or is it required to install bootstrap by `npm`?.

[image]

Comment: According to the error you are attempting to install bootstrap into a package called bootstrap. Is bootstrap already installed in the nodejs folder? Try installing it into another folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install `bootstrap` inside a directory named `bootstrap` that is why it gave you this error. just change directory name and install it

Answer (score 0):

"Did you name your project the same as the dependency you're installing?"

Fix would be renaming your project folder from bootstrap-3.3.7 to any.

Answer (score 0):

change the parent directory and then install.

and better start using `Bootstrap 4`. It is new and much better.